# Subsequent websocket session from Angular 2 to Spring backend stops previous websocket sessions from working

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using Spring Boot v1.5.1 to implement a websocket backend and Angular 2 for the front end. Basically, the backend (Spring) polls a database for changes, if there are any, pushes the changes to the frontend (Angular).

If the first user, `A`, accesses the website, then she sees all the changes. As soon as another user, `B`, accesses the website, she can see the changes but user `A` no longer does. This behavior can be replicated on the same computer by opening up 2 browsers (one after the other; the latter will see the changes but the former will have stopped).

On the backend, my websocket handler looks like the following.

```
package demo.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@Component
public class TimestampWsHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    private WebSocketSession session;

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        this.session = session;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        String payload = message.getPayload();
        if ("CLOSE".equalsIgnoreCase(payload)) {
            session.close();
            return;
        }
    }

    void push() {
        if (null != session && session.isOpen()) {
            String s = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                    .mapToObj(i -> System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .map(i -> i.toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            try {
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(s));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void start() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                push();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500L);
                } catch (Exception e) { }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

My Spring Boot application entry point looks like the following.

```
package demo;

import demo.web.TimestampWsHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class App implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private TimestampWsHandler timestampWsHandler;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(timestampWsHandler, "/api/ws/topic/timestamp").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

On the frontend (after using `ng cli` to create the project), my `app.component.ts` has been modified to look like the following.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { IntervalObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';
import { $WebSocket, WebSocketSendMode } from 'angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  data: Array<String>;
  ws: $WebSocket;
  wsSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initWebSocket();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyWebSocket();
  }

  private initWebSocket(): void {
    this.ws = new $WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/api/ws/topic/timestamp');
    this.wsSubscription = this.ws.getDataStream().subscribe(
      msgEvent => {
        this.data = msgEvent.data.split(',');
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }

  private destroyWebSocket(): void {
    if (this.wsSubscription) {
      try {
        this.wsSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this.wsSubscription = null;
      } catch (err) { }
    }

    if (this.ws) {
      try {
        this.ws.close(true);
        this.ws = null;
      } catch (err) { }
    }
  }
}
```

And the corresponding HTML, `app.component.html` looks like the following.

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<table *ngIf="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>timestamp</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let t of data">
      <td>{{t}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note, that after I created the Angular application, I had to install [angular2-websocket](https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket): `npm install angular2-websocket --save`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I do see the following `IllegalStateException` being repeated over and over. I'm not sure if these problems are related.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.checkState(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:1224)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.textPartialStart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:1182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:49)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:203)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:101)
        at demo.web.TimestampWsHandler.push(TimestampWsHandler.java:37)
        at demo.web.TimestampWsHandler.lambda$start$2(TimestampWsHandler.java:47)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your handler is a singleton and one session is overriding the other. Never keep state in a singleton.

Comment: how can i fix this to work?

Comment: Isn't that obvious, by not storing the state in your handler..Pass it to the start method and store it in the anonymous class instead of in the singleton...

Comment: In general, I agree with you to not store state in the singleton. But, wouldn't I need a reference (which could be interpreted as state) to each and every single `WebSocketSession`? I can see the situation where I would want to close or clean up resources as a result of each connecting session, and they all come through the handler, so the handler must be able to route these state changes (perhaps to the anonymous class).

Comment: Yes you do and hence you need to pass it to the class you are creating internally... Your `new Thread() {}` is basically an anonymous class just pass the reference to that.